# Laravel edit form won't display old date if it is in format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Tags: mysql, forms, laravel, input, laravel-5

I have a standard edit form for all my models:

```
{!! Form::input('date', 'date_event',  @$object->date_event) !!}
```

### problem

If the date format stored in my MySQL database is like this `2017-02-25 17:00:00`, the `@$object->date_event` would not set the datepicker properly - as a result the form would store `0000-00-00 00:00:00` when I submit it.
It is destructive - the old value of this field is erased.

### Additional notes:

I have changed cell type to datetime, varchar(32), timestamp - partly just to experiment with the problem. I have concluded that the necessary condition to show the date is to store it in this format `0000-00-00`
But I need hours and minutes too.

#### datepicker

in Chrome I don't use any extra datepicker. I use version 50.0.2661.102 m
in Firefox the datepicker is not working at all - the field acts like a `text` type.

### To do:

make the form see the date even if it is in this format: `2017-02-25 17:00:00`.

Thx

Comment: You need to specify what datepicker you are using - expected format may depend on that

Comment: ok, I have updated the question. I have no 3rd party datepicker.

Comment: A quick research says that 1) Firefox doesn't support native date fields at all (you have to use a JS plugin 2) Chrome expects date only. You cannot choose date and time at the same time - meaning your database column type should be date only, not datetime.

Comment: Thanks for dragging me out of darkness. Is there any datepicker to handle the issue for my purposes?

Comment: This one http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php is quite good :) there are several more, all with good compatibility